# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taggit' in Django 3

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am  getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taggit' when trying to load my app.
However, I have installed 'taggit'

Comment: Just curious, you have installed the module and you have added it to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py and then it throws the ModuleNotFoundError, right?

Comment: Hello bimmui, yes correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.